# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8/20/2014' then how i fit the train dataset to the model dataset

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

[This image may be useful for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxxpJ.png)Can someone please help me try to fix these errors?  It does not fit the training data set to the model dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv('./DATA/kc_house_data.csv')
X=df.drop('price',axis=1).values
y=df['price'].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_test, X_train, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler=MinMaxScaler()
X_train=scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=scaler.transform(X_test)
print(X_train.shape())
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(19,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(19,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(19,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(19,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')
print(model.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),batch_size=128,epochs=400))
```

[This image may be used for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxxpJ.png)

Comment: `'8/20/2014'` looks like a date ... not a float ... hardcode a df/[edit] your code to include a full [mre] so we can see it. We do not have your file to experiment with.

Comment: I had post image of code that may be helpfull for you

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Atleast you should try to find out these errors